# How do I use a flatMap in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have a list:

```
case class Dog(age: Int)
val dogs: List[Dog] = Dog(5) :: Dog(2) :: Dog(2) :: Dog(4) :: Dog(4) :: Dog(4) :: Dog(8) :: Nil
```

I will do the list that it will create the number of children equal to the dog's age. Could you help me?  Thanks!!!

Result that I want is: List[Dog] = List[Dog(5),Dog(5),Dog(5),Dog(5),Dog(5), Dog(2),Dog(2), Dog(2),Dog(2)),Dog(4),Dog(4),Dog(4),Dog(4),Dog(4),Dog(4),Dog(4),Dog(4),Dog(4),Dog(4),Dog(4),Dog(4), Dog(8),Dog(8),Dog(8),Dog(8), Dog(8),Dog(8),Dog(8),Dog(8)]

Comment: Your question is not clear. Providing a sample of the expected output may help.

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> case class Dog(age: Int)
defined class Dog

scala> val dogs: List[Dog] = Dog(5) :: Dog(2) :: Dog(2) :: Dog(4) :: Dog(4) :: Dog(4) :: Dog(8) :: Nil
dogs: List[Dog] = List(Dog(5), Dog(2), Dog(2), Dog(4), Dog(4), Dog(4), Dog(8))

scala> dogs.groupBy(_.age).mapValues(_.size)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(8 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 5 -> 1, 4 -> 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, so you might want to clean it up, but I think I understand what you mean - assuming your Dog is defined something like

```
case class Dog(age: Int)
```

Then you can create a map like this

```
val doggies = dogs map(i => i.age -> i) toMap
doggies: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Dog] = Map(5 -> Dog(5), 2 -> Dog(2), 4 -> Dog(4), 8 -> Dog(8))
```

BTW, you can create your list like this if you like:

```
val dogs: List[Dog] = List(Dog(5), Dog(2), Dog(2), Dog(4), Dog(4), Dog(4), Dog(8))
```

**EDIT**

I've seen you've changed your question, you want this

```
scala> dogs.flatMap(i => List.fill(i.age)(i))
```

res13: List[Dog] = List(Dog(5), Dog(5), Dog(5), Dog(5), Dog(5), Dog(2), Dog(2), Dog(2), Dog(2), Dog(4), Dog(4), Dog(4), Dog(4), Dog(4), Dog(4), Dog(4), Dog(4), Dog(4), Dog(4), Dog(4), Dog(4), Dog(8), Dog(8), Dog(8), Dog(8), Dog(8), Dog(8), Dog(8), Dog(8))

where List.fill(n)(e) will create a list of e f's

Answer (score 0):

pretty simple I guess:

list.flatMap(dog => {for (i <- (0 to dog.age) ) yield dog.clone} )